# Is decision logic a client or server side responsibility?

Tags: database, rest, client

I had some debate with a colleague regard how the logic of add/delete entries should work.

So the problem is that an object has following properties

```
{
   foo: []
}
```

When adding more to the foo list, user can click save

Wherein a REST method is called to add the new entries in the `foo` property.

So next time the object looks like following

```
{
   foo: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

User this time delete `1` and then re-adds it. And click save.
Nothing should happen.

The actual call to REST method occurs when save is clicked.

My colleague, says to simplify things on client side, it should only need to call the REST method which does add. And the REST method should add all the entries again. So he wants the add method to basically remove every entries related to that object and re-add all of them again.

I'm against this because it does unneeded work. I could write logic to check which entry is new. However since this is a business class of application I don't think putting that logic on server side is a good idea because of cost. Instead I think it should be resolved on the client side.

So that the REST method to add does what it does, it adds new entries, and not do two things which are delete all entries and then add all entries.

**Examples on call to REST method**

```
Add
POST: REST/{objectId}?entries=1,2,3
```

Result entries = [1,2,3]

```
Remove
DELETE: REST/{objectId}?entries=1
```

Result entries = [2,3]

Comment: The debate between you and your colleague seems interesting. But, to better understand the debate, can you give us some specific example of your "REST method"?

Comment: @realharry added example

Answer (score 1):

> ".. I think it should be resolved on the client side.."

I disagree. The REST service should be a black box and the client doesn't have to be aware of the logic to add or remove items, it's server's responsibility.

Comment: In addition to your answer I would say that it's the back job to see that the item to remove/add is the same and so ignore the request.

Comment: So the two of you mean that same REST method should have to responsibility? Which are `add` and `remove`?

Answer (score 0):

> My colleague, says to simplify things on client side, it should only need to call the REST method which does add. And the REST method should add all the entries again. So he wants the add method to basically remove every entries related to that object and re-add all of them again.

I disagree with that. Imagine yo have 10k entries, why delete 9 999 entries just to delete one item?

> I'm against this because it does unneeded work.

You are right. In addition, maybe you will do unnecessary requests to database and deteriorate access to it.

The client must not know this logic. it doesn't have all elements to take the decision to add or delete an element into the resource. So, the client asks to API to do an action and the API answers it if the action is done or not.

If you put the logic in the backend your API in more reusable. Tomorrow, you have another client of your API, why rewrite the logic of add or delete in the client side? Normally, it's the same.

Comment: That's what I thought so too, but I guess it boils down to where the logic to handle the filtering of what is `added` and what should be `removed` should reside. Which I also hoped for it can be in the client side

Answer (score 0):

So, let's suppose that you currently have

```
{ foo = [1, 3, 4] }.
```

A POST method is called:

```
REST/{objectId}?entries=1,2
```

What happens? Based on your description, I would suppose it would result in

```
{ foo = [1, 2] }
```

not [1, 2, 3, 4]. If that's the case, then I think your colleague is right. You have to remove existing items, and re-add the newly specified entries. In this case, your REST method should really be PUT not POST.

Now, on the other hand, if you expect the result to be

```
{ foo = [1, 2, 3, 4] }
```

not [1, 2], then your approach seems more reasonable. In this case, your REST method seems to be semantically closer to PATCH than POST.

This is an interesting example since you're manipulating "sub-resources" not the resource itself ({...} in your example, which includes foo).